# error when trying to install pip on mac 10.7

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to download pip onto my mac by following the instructions on the pip installation guide and I am coming up with this error after running the following command

```
$python get-pip.py

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/
MacOS/Python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is happening after I download the 'get-pip.py' doc as the instructions suggest. Do I need to put this file in a certain location before I continue? I am relatively new to downloading programs through the terminal.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is recommended (*highly*) that you **NOT** use the version of Python that ships with your Mac. Instead use [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh) and install a "custom" version of Python (*usually the latest*). Then proceed to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and optionally [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper)

**Prerequisites:**

1. First, install Xcode from the App Store (*it's FREE*).

**Install HomeBrew:**

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

**Install Python:**

```
brew install python
```

This will install pip for you as well in `/usr/local/bin/`.

**Install virtualenv:**

```
pip install virtualenv
```

**virtualenv Basic Usage:**

```
virtualenv /path/to/my/env
cd /path/to/my/env
source ./bin/activate

# hack on your python project
deactivate  # to go back to your normal shell
```

Please follow instructions for [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for more details.

[virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) is also really convenient and worthwhile learning.

Answer (score 6):

**Update** :

More explanation at @dval 's comment

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
```

and then execute

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

Comment: what's special with your answer?

Comment: This works because you download get-pip.py into your working directory, which is where the python interpreter will start searching for the file.  It has nothing to do with how the file was downloaded, only where python was looking. if the OP had done a `cd ~/Downloads` before invoking python, it probably would have worked.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me, so I decided to straight out clean install Python 3.6 from the downloads page at [python.org](https://www.python.org/).

After you have completed the Python installer, go into Terminal and type in:

`curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

Wait for the download to complete and then type in:

`python3 get-pip.py --user`

Then for your pip commands you will use 'pip3'. For example:

```
pip3 install awsebcli --upgrade --user
```

After python and pip have been installed they should be in your user Library. So update your PATH in terminal like so:

```
export PATH=~/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

I have a bash_profile shell so I also ran the following command in terminal to load script into my current session:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After this, verify that your pip installed component was successful.
For example:

```
eb --version
```

See [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html) for the above reference.

Answer (score 0):

Curl did not work for me. I had to use "wget".

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
```

and then execute

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

Comment: all you really need to do to download pip is make sure you are in the same directory that you downloaded the file to (typically your 'download' folder) in your terminal or command prompt and then run $python get-pip.py.